# Circular dependency when installing numpy

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

I am trying to install numpy in my virtualenv but I face circular dependencies as follow:

```
(test) [hadoop@ip-192-168-26-8 test]$ python -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/20/4d43e141b5bc426ba38274933ef8e76e85c7adea2c321ecf9ebf7421cedf/numpy-1.18.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 requires grpcio>=1.24.3, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 requires markdown>=2.6.8, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 requires protobuf>=3.6.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 requires werkzeug>=0.11.15, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.1
```

then when I try to install grpcio

```
(test) [hadoop@ip-192-168-26-8 test]$ python -m pip install grpcio
Collecting grpcio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/8f/f79c5c174bebece41f824dd7b1ba98da45dc2d4c373b38ac6a7f6a5acb5e/grpcio-1.26.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in ./lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from grpcio) (1.14.0)
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 requires markdown>=2.6.8, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 requires numpy>=1.12.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 requires protobuf>=3.6.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 requires werkzeug>=0.11.15, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: grpcio
Successfully installed grpcio-1.26.0
```

I am not even sure why it gives me incorrect prompt `Successfully installed grpcio-1.26.0`, as they are not being added to my pip when I use list command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind uninstalling numpy with below:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

And install it again with --no-cache-dir option:

```
pip install numpy --no-cache-dir
```

Also, see that pip is upgraded.